# Thread 1:breakpoint 1.3 error in AppDelegate.m file

Tags: objective-c

I am getting a runtime error in my AppDelegate.m file; the project compiles fine, but won't display in the iOS Simulator. In the file, I get a green arrow saying Thread 1:breakpoint 1.3 error which I can't figure out.

When it completes running, I get a stack trace pointing to this line, but haven't found anything wrong with the code. I have commented out the line where the problem is. Can you tell me what's wrong?

WhereamiAppDelegate.m

```
#import "WhereamiAppDelegate.h"

#import "WhereamiViewController.h"

@implementation WhereamiAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
  self.viewController = [[WhereamiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereamiViewController" bundle:nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; // Thread 1: breakpoint 1.3
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
  // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
  // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your xib files for deleted outlets that are still linked:
[image]

I guess the first priority to check is your root view controller's xib file `WhereamiViewController.xib`

Comment: Thank  you very much; that was exactly the problem! I had an outlet with the wrong name, and as soon as I deleted it, it worked. Thanks again!